# FsUnit and checking equality of floating point numbers

Tags: f#, nunit, fsunit

I started using FsUnit to test F# code. It makes it possible to express assertion in F# style, for example:

```
[<Test>]
member this.``Portugal voted for 23 countries in 2001 Eurovision contest``() =
    this.totalVotes 
    |> getYearVotesFromCountry "Portugal" 2001
    |> Seq.length
    |> should equal 23
```

Note "should equal 23" that I get from FsUnit. Here's how FsUnit defines it:

let equal x = new EqualConstraint(x)

With floating point numbers it's not that simple. I have to use EqualConstraint with Within method. It naturally fits C#:

```
Assert.That(result).Is.EqualTo(1).Within(0.05);
```

Of course I'd like to be able to write in F#:

```
result |> should equal 1 within 0.05
```

But that does not work. I ended up defining a new function:

```
let almostEqual x = (new EqualConstraint(x)).Within(0.01)
```

or if I want to parametrize precision, I can specify it as a second argument:

```
let equalWithin x y = (new EqualConstraint(x)).Within(y)
```

But none of them are pretty. I would like to define "within" function in a more natural way for F#, so it can be used together with equal. F# does not support method overloading, so it looks like I can't define it in such a way so "equal" can be used either alone or together with "within".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an interesting problem! I don't think that you can append `within 0.05` to the existing definition of `should equal` in any way. To do that you would need to add parameter to the `should` function, but that needs to have a fixed number of parameters in the library.

One way to write this elegantly in F# would is to create custom operator `+/-`. Note that you still need to use parentheses, but it looks quite neat:

```
0.9 |> should equal (1.0 +/- 0.5)
```

The operator simply constructs some value of a special type that needs to be explicitly handled in the `equal` function. Here is the implementation:

```
type Range = Within of float * float
let (+/-) (a:float) b = Within(a, b)

let equal x = 
  match box x with 
  | :? Range as r ->
      let (Within(x, within)) = r
      (new EqualConstraint(x)).Within(within)
  | _ ->
    new EqualConstraint(x)
```

Comment: Wow! It is quite need indeed! Thanks for another great suggestion. And this one is also based on custom operators.

Answer (score 0):

Terminology note: F# does support *method* overloading; it does not support overloading *let-bound functions* ('free' functions defined in modules).

You could e.g. make it `should.equal` with a dot, so that `equal` is a method on the `should` object, which you could overload.  Although that still wouldn't help, since you can't overload curried arguments.  Hmmm.

Ok, I don't have much helpful to offer.  Personally I don't like these type of syntactic sugars in libraries.

Comment: You're right Brian in terminology. I meant let-bound functions of course.

And I enjoy this syntactic sugar. I think it's essential in F#.